# How to debug/audit which devices cache writes?

Tags: linux-mint, cache, btrfs, dm-crypt

I store documents on btrfs partition built upon sparse dm-crypt device located on ext4 main partition on physical harddrive.

When kernel panics (and this happens on daily basis on my ASUS P53E with 3.6 kernel :-( ) I loose recently modified files (always the files' contents got replaced with zeros).

One way of preventing damage to files it is to disable the write cache.

For this I would need to disable write caching for the btrfs partition, the dm-crypt device that backs the partition, and for the sparse file where dm-crypt device lives.

1. How can I check the cache-write status for the drives?
2. How can I disable it?

I use Mint 13 Maya with 3.6.8 mainline kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure the disk drives write cache is going to fix the issue for you as it sounds like you are using a loop device. So there is still the page cache/file in between your Btrfs filesystem and the actual disk. The same type of issue exists for journaling filesystems [detailed here for loop-AES](https://superuser.com/questions/266161/encryption-loop-device-and-journaling-file-system-on-linux). So when data is synced to your loop device, it may not be on real disk yet just in a cache waiting to be re ordered and written out.

ext4 doesn't support the `sync` mount option ext2/3 did to disable caching. due to the layers in between I'm not sure even that would get you an effective recovery. I don't know enough about the internals unfortunately, at least more data would make it to disc.

In the same way you might be able to *limit* the issue by tuning the page cache so the system writes out to disk more often. The linux page cache reports it's values in `/proc/meminfo` under

```
"Dirty" - for pages that are currently dirty
"Writeback" - for dirty pages that are being written out to disk.
```

There are files in [`/proc/sys/vm/`](http://www.linuxinsight.com/proc_sys_vm_hierarchy.html) that report status and control the flush threads that write data back to disk.

You could put a small value (greater than 8096 or 2 pages) in [`/proc/sys/vm/dirty_background_bytes`](http://www.linuxinsight.com/proc_sys_vm_dirty_background_bytes.html) to make the background pdflush process run more actively or [`/proc/sys/vm/dirty_bytes`](http://www.linuxinsight.com/proc_sys_vm_dirty_bytes.html) to make a process trigger flush more actively (For a performance penalty, or at least more disk writes overall).

I think it's unlikely the hardware write cache is where your main issue lies. If you were only going direct to the device via dm-crypt then I'd look there first. In any case IDE and SATA write caches can be disabled with `hdparm -W0 /dev/xdx`.

Also as your using a, technically, experimental file system in a more edge case way than most you might have better luck with a more mature fs where people have stumbled into the issues already. If you need Btrfs, the best bet would be to do the encryption to a physical partition.

Answer (score 0):

So far I have found a way of setting write-cache behavior for physical partition (`/dev/sda6` in my case):

`sudo hdparm -W /dev/sda6` for inspecting the write behavior and `sudo hdparm -W0 /dev/sda6` for disabling the write-cache.

But it is an overkill in my situation; I want only to disable write-cache for the file backing the dm-crypt, not the entire partition.

Comment: Sorry.. had the answer window open for too long to see this before my post. I'm not aware of a system way you can do this. You can provide an [O_DIRECT](http://superuser.com/questions/242928/disable-linux-read-and-write-file-cache-on-partition) option when opening a file so it should be possible for the loop driver to open the file that way. Whether or not that includes modifying source code is another question =) Maybe loop already does that and the issue does lies somewhere else...

Comment: @mindthemonkey The hdparm trick described above did solve the issue once, but I'm my (involuntary :-( ) tests are still inconclusive. I moved the documents out of the sparse file into physical, encrypted with dm-crypt partition. I hope it will improve the robustness of the storage.